# How to trace the parameters and equations that are used to calculate the mass on the pipeline in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

The components in Modelica contain equations, parameters which are used to calculate the state and variables for the whole system. For example, in a power plant model, the key variables are pressure, enthalpy, and mass flow rate. 
Assuming I am interested in the mass flow on some pipeline, how could I trace the equations and parameters that are used to calculate the mass flow rate on this pipeline?

[image]

Comment: You could use the OpenModelica Transformational Debugger to find out how the system of equations is solved by the Modelica compiler.

Comment: The problem is that I am using the Thermal Power library provided by Modelon, it only works in Dymola.

Comment: Commercial encrypted libraries might work in future versions of OpenModelica: https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/encryption.html Still, debugging capabilities might be impacted/limited by the encryption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Simulation Setup, Translation, activate "Provide variable dependencies for plotting", this is equal to setting the flag `Advanced.GenerateVariableDependencies := true;`. 
In the results you can then right-click on the variable and click "Plot Dependencies", and you will see the equation how it was calculated.

[image]

As an alternative, in Simulation Setup, Translation, activate "Generate listing of translated Modelica code in dsmodel.mof" and then search for the variable name in that dsmodel.mof file.

Comment: Assuming there are two equations (A and B) for calculating variable Alpha, how could I know that equation A belongs to which component?